# What's the most idiomatic way to model this relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say we have coaches, clients, and users.

What's the ideal way to model this in a way that isn't inheritance? I'd like to avoid STI.

Right now I have something like this:

user.rb

```
  has_many :coaches, :foreign_key => :client_id
  has_many :coach_users, :through => :coaches, :source => :user
  has_many :clients, :class_name => "Coach"
  has_many :client_users, :through => :clients, :source => :client


  def is_a_coach_of?(client)
    self.client_users.include?(client)
  end

  def is_a_client_of?(coach)
    self.coach_users.include?(coach)
  end
```

coach.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => "User"
```

But this feels really clunky to deal with a User object that is supposedly a 'coach' and having to type user.coach_users to get a collection of users that are being coached by this specific user.

It feels very non idiomatic and quite honestly, it's just plain confusing and I hate it. I want something more elegant.

I thought of removing the join model and just having two has_many's on the user.rb model but it still feels clunky, especially the icky feeling of violating roles of objects. These are different roles but are also very similar because they're all a user. How do you separate such common logic in an elegant way, in the right idiomatic way with Rails and Ruby?

A "user of the site" **can** exist without being a `coach` or a `client`.

If the modeling requires just a relationship, then I can see it be a HABTM but what if the individual relationship requires extra logic? E.g extra logic on client or coach? Would you just mixin a class that defines logic in the User model? Or would you create separate AR models for the relationship and if so, how?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using STI? This is a good case for it.

Comment: From what I gather, STI is usually a bad solution to the problem but if that's the perfect case...

Comment: STI works well if done properly despite being very easy to misuse. Note that `User` will become an abstract class and you must only interact with it through it's subclasses. For example, must instantiate a `Coach` or a `Client`, never a `User`. Still, lots of people break that rule, incorporating dirty hacks to curtail Rails' built-in support, get frustrated and write blog posts chastising STI as a "bad solution." If you're willing to give up control of `User`, I'll write up an answer for you.

Comment: That's the thing though, there will be users as well. A user can exist without being a `client` or a `coach`. A client or coach is just a type of relationship between users that may or may not have that relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `client`/`coach` is just a relationship, it can be just that, not a separate model. So you can do a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Users`. Create a migration with:

```
  def up
    create_table :coaches_clients do |t|
      t.integer :coach_id
      t.integer :client_id
    end
  end
```

and in you model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients,
        :foreign_key => 'client_id',
        :association_foreign_key => 'coach_id',
        :class_name => 'User',
        :join_table => 'coaches_clients'

has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches,
        :foreign_key => 'coach_id',
        :association_foreign_key => 'client_id',
        :class_name => 'User',
        :join_table => 'coaches_clients'
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Makes sense. If you were to take a precaution on the fact that a client or coach may need additional logic how would you model it in that sense ?

Comment: It really depends on your needs, but I find it convenient to have a `user` model, that `has_one` coach model and `has_one` client model. That way, you can have user details and logic having to do with that in the user separately and a user can be a coach, a client, both or neither. That way the coach logic can go in the `coach` model. Not sure how idiomatic it is, I guess you would be calling `user.coach.clients` and such.